# Can't install openSUSE 13.2 from USB - linuxrc launches

Tags: linux, installation, usb, opensuse

OK, so I would like to install openSUSE 13.2 64bit with my USB (want to install it, not to use LiveCD - so i downloaded installation 4.7GB iso). I have used Universal USB Installer 1.9.5.7 to create installation media. Everything worked without problem. When I boot from it, first a openSUSE screen shows up with options Install, Upgrade, Something-I-Don't-Remember and Check installation media. If I choose Install, terminal shows and at the end it says that it  is launching "openSUSE installation program". After that, a graphically stunning screen with header "linuxrc" (seems to be responsible for launching installer) shows up and asks me to insert installation media and then press Yes to continue. If I click yes, it shows again, if I click no, it shows me another screen with options Install, Check disk integrity, Reboot and so on... I choose install and it asks for source medium. Options are CD/Network/HDD. However, I want to install it from an USB.

So, my question is: What am I doing wrong? Because I got that feeling that after choosing Install in the first screen (that one with openSUSE background), something else should happen instead of showing up linuxrc. Like launching or whatever. Or should I use another app to "burn" my ISO on USB?

Comment: In my opinion you're doing it right. 13.2.rc something (4.7gb iso) wasn't working for me as well. But yesterday I successfully installed system from live-cd(live usb in fact). Just try another iso.

Comment: Yes. It is possible to install from live-cd. There is a menu item `installation`

Comment: OK but I managed to find a sollution even for DVD (as stated in answer below). Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i just managed to make it work.
I am using ISO downloaded today morning (5.November 2014 at 13:11) and ImageWriter ( http://www.mediafire.com/download/9haeauu9sq8xtkx/ImageWriter.exe ). And it seems to work. If you get error about writeToDisk, close the program and launch it as Administrator (i mean it, right click and select run as administrator, it asks you for admin password even if you launch it with doubleclick but it won't work). Then find your file (it shows only *.*raw files in open dialog so you will have to just start writing iso file name in Open bar), choose right device and it will do the hard work. If it finishes with "Sucess" message box, restart PC and boot from USB. Then select Installation.